# false code coverage reported using GwtMockito

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco, eclemma, gwtmockito

Is there any reason why `EclEmma(JaCoCo based)` in Eclipse falsely reports the code coverage while using the `GwtMockitoTestRunner`?

Looking at it's source code, it does install it's own class loader and does byte code manipulation using the `Javassist library`. Could this affect the code coverage tool anyhow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that EclEmma/JaCoCo doesn't work well with final methods and with native methods(GWT JSNI code).

Fixing these methods everything returned to normal, the coverage is reported correctly.